# Objective-c anonymous property coding style

Tags: coding-style, coding-standards, objective-c

If I have an interface defined like

```
@interface MyClass

@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *myString;

@end
```

so that `myString` is externally visible but can't be written, what would be the preferred coding style for redeclaring the property in the implementation? Would it be (a)

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
```

or (b)

```
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *myString;
```

(I know that these two are exactly the same, this is a question purely about coding style!)

Comment: Afaik just mentioning `(readwrite)` in the implementation will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred coding style would be (b) according to all style guides that I've seen (e.g. https://github.com/objc-zen/objc-zen-book#property-declaration). They recommend explicitly specify `readwrite` attribute (for the sake of clarity, I guess).

Comment: I disagree - this answers my question perfectly. I don't know why it's been down-voted!